# How to count based on data that I've selected (varchar)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Questions may not be so right, I'm struggling with the wording.

So I have two tables

```
Course(
CourseID VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
CourseName VARCHAR(255),
Credit INT
)

StudentScore(
StudentID BIGINT ,
Semester INT ,
CourseID VARCHAR(8) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course(CourseID),
TotalScore INT PRIMARY KEY,
Grade VARCHAR(2) 
)
```

I want to select semester, courseid, coursename, #students and A, A-, B+. #students stands for counting the number of students that attends the selected course, and the A, A-, B+ stands for counting the students who has the Grade A, A- or B+

I've come up with

```
SELECT Semester, a.CourseID AS [Course ID], CourseName AS [Course Name], #Students = COUNT(*), A = COUNT(Grade) 
FROM StudentScore a JOIN Course b ON a.CourseID = b.CourseID
Group By Semester, a.CourseID, CourseName
```

, but still I'm struggling with the conditions, don't know what to put in the WHERE, whether to put the WHERE on the count if I can do that. I tried to put the WHERE in the COUNT, but it doesn't work as I can't put CourseID or Grade as the condition

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a blind guess, but are you not after conditional aggregation?

```sql
SELECT SS.Semester,
       SS.CourseID AS [Course ID],
       C.CourseName AS [Course Name],
       COUNT(*) AS #Students,
       COUNT(CASE SS.Grade WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) AS A,
       COUNT(CASE SS.Grade WHEN 'A-' THEN 1 END) AS [A-],
       COUNT(CASE SS.Grade WHEN 'B+' THEN 1 END) AS [B+]
FROM dbo.StudentScore SS --Student Score doesnt' have a single "a" in it, why use "a" as the alias?
     JOIN dbo.Course C ON SS.CourseID = C.CourseID --"b" for Course? Course starts with a "C", not a "b".
GROUP BY SS.Semester,
         SS.CourseID,
         C.CourseName;
```

Also, some required reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)